# Remove duplicate items in array that have comma separating values

Tags: php, arrays, csv, duplicates, delimited

I have an array of languages that looks like this:
(this data is pulled from mysql stored as: e.g. field value: greek, polish)

```
 Array
(
[0] => 
[1] => french
[2] => french, greek
[3] => german
[4] => greek
[5] => greek, polish
[6] => italian
[7] => spanish
[8] => spanish, italian
[9] => spanish, portuguese
)
```

I have tried using array_unique($languages) but the output stays the same.

I assume it is because of the comma.

Any idea on how to just have unique values?
e.g. one each of: french, greek, german, polish, italian, spanish, and portuguese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a plain array from input

```
$res = array();
foreach ($array  as $item)
  $res = array_merge($res, explode(', ', $item));
```

and then use `array_unique($res)`

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = array_map(function ($item) {
    // explode values by "," and trim spaces
    return array_map('trim', explode(',', $item));
}, $your_data);

// merge all nested arrays from $data and return unique
return array_unique(
    call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data);
);
```

Your result will be:

```
Array
(
[0] => 
[1] => french
[2] => greek
[3] => german
[4] => polish
[5] => italian
[6] => spanish
[7] => portuguese
)
```

Comment: @user2413654. Ok. Splash58's code less, because he not trim values.

Comment: It is not necessary for splash58 to trim the values, because `explode()` is (properly) splitting on all comma-space instances.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
function getUniqueSubValues($array) {
    $result = [];
    foreach($array as $element) {
        $result += preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $element);
    }
    return array_unique($result);
}
```

I'm looping over all values inside the array and splitting each of them further into subvalues.

I'm using `preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', ...)` instead of `explode(',', ...)` because otherwise the space after the `,` would be kept and we would have to trim it.

I'm merging all subvalues into the results array, and at the end I'm returning the unique values of that array.